# Is there a faster approach to Project Euler #9?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

My solution (in Javascript):

```
for(var a=1; a<333; a++) {
  var b = Math.floor(1000 * (a-500) / (a-1000));
  var c = 1000-a-b;
  (a*a+b*b===c*c && b>0) && console.log(a*b*c);
}
```

The problem can be found [here](https://projecteuler.net/problem=9). It is to find a * b * c where a+b+c=1000 and a, b, and c are a Pythagorean triple.

My code can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/justinpchang/bLhx55oc/5/). My solution only loops through one variable up to 333 times instead of solutions with embedded for loops, or the solution with one for loop and a while loop to calculate the triple found [here](http://www.mathblog.dk/pythagorean-triplets/) that uses a square root.

The rationale is as follows:

It is given that a+b+c=1000 and that a, b, and c form a Pythagorean triple. It follows that a < b < c, so a has a maximum value of 333. Additionally, since a^2+b^2=c^2, c=sqrt(a^2+b^2). Combining this equation with c=1000-a-b, c can be eliminated, producing the equation [b=1000(a-500)/(a-1000)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(a%5E2%2Bb%5E2)%20%3D%201000-a-b%20solve%20for%20b).

The Math.floor() is to eliminate cases where b is a decimal (and therefore also where c is a decimal). The b>0 check is obviously to make sure b is not negative.

Is there a faster approach?

Comment: Please post your details here, not just as links to the Euler site.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry about that. I fixed the question.

Comment: There are only a handful of Pythagorean triples that are integers below 1000, and larger ones are just multiples of the smaller ones. You could just test these known sets.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple

Comment: Once you have solved the problem you should click on the link to the problems thread.  This is where people post alternative algorithms for project Euler problems.  In particular, look at the third comment (by Pier) which explains how to solve this problem without any programming at all.

Comment: The `&& b>0` is superfluous. If a < 500 (which is the case, a < 333) then b cannot become negative.